# Why does Scala Immutable Vector not provide an insertAt method?

Tags: scala

Scala Immutable Vector is implemented using a Relaxed Radix Balanced Trees, which provides single element append in log (n) complexity like an HAMT but also log (n) insertAt and concatenation.

Why does the API does not expose insertAt?

Comment: Scala immutable vector is currently *not* implemented as a Relaxed Radix Balanced Tree. There was some discussion about this, but so far nothing came of it.

Comment: Is that a HAMT with 32 bit branching faxtor?

Comment: The current implementation is a tree with a branching factor of 32 and various clever tweaks. No hashing involved though, so HAMT does not really fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `insertAt` method (neglecting performance issues) operating on immutable vectors. Just the rough method sketch here

```
def insertAt[T]( v: Vector[T], elem: T, pos: Int) : Vector[T] = {
  val n = v.size
  val front = v.take(pos)
  val end = v.takeRight(n-pos)
  front ++ Vector(elem) ++ end
}
```

Call:

```
val x = Vector(1,2,3,5)
println( insertAt( x, 7, 0) )
println( insertAt( x, 7, 1) )
println( insertAt( x, 7, 2) )
```

Output:

```
Vector(7, 1, 2, 3, 5)
Vector(1, 7, 2, 3, 5)
Vector(1, 2, 7, 3, 5)
```

Not handled properly in this sketch

- types.
- index checking.

Use the *pimp-my-library* pattern to add that to the Vector class.

### Edit: Updated version of `insertAt`

```
def insertAt[T]( v: Vector[T], elem: T, pos: Int) : Vector[T] =
  v.take(pos) ++ Vector(elem) ++ v.drop(pos)
```

Comment: That means, I haven't done any performance tests. Source code of `immutable.Vector` says: "It is backed by a little endian bit-mapped vector trie with a branching factor of 32.  Locality is very good, but not contiguous, which is good for very large sequences."

Comment: Perhaps defining `insertAt` in terms of `splice` would be a little bit more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Having an efficient `insertAt` is typically not an operation I would expect from a general `Vector`, immutable or not. That's more the purview of (mutable) linked lists.

Putting an efficient `insertAt` into the public API of `Vector` would severely constrain the implementation choices for that API. While at the moment, there is only one implementation of the Scala standard library APIs (which I personally find rather unfortunate, a bit of competition wouldn't hurt, see C++, C, Java, Ruby, Python for examples of how multiple implementations can foster an environment of friendly [coopetition](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Coopetition)), there is no way to know that this will forever be the case. So, you should be very careful what guarantees you add to the public API of the Scala standard library, otherwise you might constrain both future versions of the current single implementation as well as potential alternative implementations in undue ways.

Again, see Ruby for an example, where exposing implementation details of one implementation in the API has led to severe pains for other implementors.